# Why echo splits long lines in 80 chars when printing within quotes? (And how to fix it?)

Tags: bash, echo, wc

Echoing without quotes... 1 line. Fine.

```
$ echo $(ls -1dmb /bin/*) > test
$ wc -l test
1 test
```

Echoing with quotes... 396 lines. Bad.

```
$ echo "$(ls -1dmb /bin/*)" > test
$ wc -l test
396 test
```

The problem comes when using echo for writing a file and expanding a long variable.

Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Comment: That echo is entirely pointless by the way.

Comment: Obviously, but it's just an example. The same happens for a very long variable, but the example would be huge.

Comment: Actually, the same thing *doesn't* happen for a long variable. echoing a long variable value will not truncate lines to 80 characters, `ls` is doing that itself. echoing a long variable value *will*, however, lose leading, trailing, and embedded spaces and newlines as that is the shell word splitting after variable expansion and command substitution.

Comment: Well, you are right. That happens if you construct your variable hand-written, which is something I also don't understand. But I constructed my variable with `ls` and it got truncated.

What I was trying to do is automate the writing of a config file, writing directories separated with comma, but you did not need to know that to answer the question ;).

Comment: Like I said, `ls` is doing the line wrapping. The shell is doing the newline (and extra space) dropping. Compare the output of `echo "    foo    "` to the output of `echo     foo    ` and you'll see the shell doing what the shell does with whitespace. Do that same thing with a quoted string more than 80 characters long and you **will not** see it wrap in your output (assuming you send it to `less` or a file where you can see that it didn't wrap correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is detecting that your `stdout` is not a terminal.

check the output of `ls -1dmb /bin/* | cat` vs `ls -1dmb /bin/*`. It's `ls`, who is splitting the output.

Similarly, for `ls --color=auto` case, `color` option is used, based on whether the stdout is terminal or not.

When quotes are used, `echo` is provided with a single arguments, which has embedded newlines, spaces, which are echoed as-is to file.

When quotes are not used, `echo` is provided multiple arguments, which are split by the [`IFS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator). Thus echo prints all of them in a single line.
But, [don't skip these quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)...

How to fix it:

I think, the splitting always occurs at the end of some file name & never in between a filename. So one of these 2 options may work for you:

```
ls -1dmb /bin/* | tr '\n' ' ' >test
ls -1dmb /bin/* | tr -d '\n' >test
```

Answer (score 0):

@anishsane correctly answers the topic question (that `ls` is doing the wrapping and ways to remove them) and covers the quoting issue as well but the quoting issue is responsible for the line count difference and not `ls`.

The issue here is entirely one of quoting and how command lines, echo, and command substitution all work.

The output from `"$(ls ...)"` is a single string with embedded newlines protected from the shell via the quotes. Hand that value to `echo` and `echo` spits it back out literally (with the newlines).

The output from `$(ls ...)` is a string that is unprotected from the shell and thus undergoes word splitting and whitespace normalization. Command substitution cannot terminate your command line early (you wouldn't want `echo $(ls -1)` in a directory with two files to run `echo first_file; second_file` would you?) the newlines are left as word separators between the arguments to `echo`. The shell then word splits the result on whitespace (including newlines) and gives echo a list of arguments at which point `echo` happily executes `echo first_file second_file ...` which, as you can guess, only outputs a single line of output.

Try this to see what I mean:

```
$ c() {
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"
}
$ ls *
a.sh b.sh temp
$ ls -1dmb *
a.sh, b.sh, temp
$ c "$(ls -1dmb *)"
argc: 1
argv: a.sh, b.sh, temp
$ c $(ls -1dmb *)
argc: 3
argv: a.sh,
argv: b.sh,
argv: temp
```

Comment: `but the quoting issue is responsible for the line count difference and not ls`: Well, I see it in a different way: As we know, [we prefer quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting). `ls` is splitting the output into multiple lines. The deviation from the _expected output_ starts from `ls` stage of data flow, rather than `echo "..."` stage. (This is my _opinion_...)

Comment: @anishsane `ls` is not creating one line of output, it is creating *n* lines of output (as many as are necessary to list all the files given that it is also wrapping the lines). Shell word splitting/`IFS` and the behaviour of `echo` is what makes the unquoted output one line. The `-1` argument to `ls` here is entirely misleading as it isn't doing anything even when output is going to the terminal.

Comment: ^^ Agreed. Also I agree that your comment above answers OP's question, about "why quoting shows the issue & not-quoting solves the issue." What I am saying is that the issue is already introduced by `ls`. It gets _exposed_ by quoting. When not quoted, the issue remains hidden. & yes, `-1` is indeed misleading.

Comment: @anishsane The issue in the post topic is introduced by `ls`, yeah. The issue in the body is not `ls` but `echo` and quoting. The real problem here is that the topic and the body don't agree on what question they are asking. =) Also the confusion about `-1` being meaningful isn't helping the OP at all.