# echo $(printf ...) dropping whitespace/formatting

Tags: bash, printf

I was using printf to format a number in bash:

```
$ printf -- ">>%4d\n" 1
>>   1
```

This works fine, but when i do the same thing in a subshell:

```
$ echo $(printf -- ">>%4d\n" 1)
>> 1
```

Why are the spaces removed? I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub-shell isn't doing it. Not directly.

The issue here is that you aren't quoting the sub-shell result. As such the shell is word-splitting the resulting text (which drops extraneous spaces) and then hands a list of words to echo which happily spits them back out at you (without the extra spaces).

This is essentially no different than running `echo      1` and wondering where the extra spaces went.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25686873/258523) discusses this a bit as well.

Comment: Thx, i did echo "$(printf -- ">>%4d\n" 1)", and it works as expected now. Thanks for your quick and clear answer. I will mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use quotes while using `command substitution` to get spacing right:

```
echo "$(printf -- ">>%4d\n" 1)"
>>   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link which gives a  detailed description when and why one should quote in their scripts, take a look it will be useful.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes