# Bash send variable as text through mutt without echo or printf

Tags: bash

I have the following problem:
I have a file that contains a list that I would like to format and send as an email.
Since the variable contains newlines, I can't use echo to pipe the variable into mutt. I've tried with printf but it only prints the first line of the variable. I would also like to avoid creating new files as this script runs in a sensitive place.

Here is the code for reference:

```
TEST=hello
TEST=$TEST$'\n'`cat file.txt`
echo $TEST | mutt -s "test" email@domain.com
```

gives me

```
hello line1 line2 line3 line4 line5...
```

and

```
TEST=hello
TEST=$TEST$'\n'`cat file.txt`
printf $TEST | mutt -s "test" email@domain.com
```

gives me

```
hello
```

Comment: Try `echo "$TEST"` or `printf %s\\n "$TEST"` to avoid the shell from stripping your newline characters out.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of [echo $(printf ...) dropping whitespace/formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732146/echo-printf-dropping-whitespace-formatting) but same idea.

Comment: The only thing my question and that one have in common are the words echo and printf. The core problem might be the same, but the symptoms are very different. Therefore, there is no way that while searching I would relate the two.

Comment: The symptoms are not different. The symptom is "my whitespace is disappearing". And yes, the question itself isn't the same but the issue (and solution) is the same. And no, your finding that question was not at all likely.

Comment: What you are saying is the same as "the solution for your segfaulting program can be found in this "bus error" question. Therefore your question is a duplicate". I searched for "newlines disappearing from echo". Not "Whitespace disappearing from echo".

Comment: I have no idea what you were trying to illustrate there. The solution to your problem is identical to the solution to the linked question because the problem is the same. The problem here was shell word-splitting collapsing newlines (and runs of whitespace) into a space character. That is the same as the problem in the question I linked and the solution to both is the same. Quote the whitespace to protect it. I'm not exactly sure what you are objecting to either.

Comment: I already said your failure to find the other question isn't your fault but that doesn't change the fact that they are semi-duplicate.

Comment: Fine then. I will send a letter to the World Health Organization saying that radiation and selenium poisoning are duplicate diseases.

Comment: I seriously have no idea what you are going on about at this point.

Comment: I don'd know what the effects of either of those are well enough to comment but if the symptoms and treatment of them are identical then having a single entry in a "book of disease treatments" would make more sense then having two would. Otherwise I still fail to see what point you think you are making and what point of mine you are objecting to.

Comment: They have exactly the same treatment and symptoms, but are completely different diseases.

Comment: So in a book listing all possible diseases you wouldn't combine them but in a book about treatments you could. But that's not really relevant since both the cause **and** symptoms here are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Etan, putting the variable dereferencing inside quotes as such `echo "$TEST"` tells echo to leave the newlines alone.